# Password management when adding VS2017 solution to GIT?

Tags: git, asp.net-core, passwords

I was going to add my project to GIT.  This project publishes a web page and the password is saved and encrypted in pubxml

However, I assume anyone who does a pull also gets my password.  They might not know what it is but I assume they could publish a lot of crap on my domain.

I can easily uncheck my password but are there any other problems I should be aware of?  There is no SQL or any database linkage in this project.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to remove it from the history in your repo, i.e. history rewritting. The [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) might help you. Or you change your password ;)

Comment: I unchecked the "Save Password"  and did a "clean solution" before I checked the sources into my new git hub.  All I see in the remote repository are .cs .asp and .config  No binaries so I think I am ok.  I did not zip up the "works" and upload the zip.